# Adjusting directive template based on element attributes

Tags: angularjs

I would like to know how to dynamically add attribute or property to a specific mark-up in my template. I have my directive like this:

```
app.directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        template:
            '<div><label>Label: </label><input id="my-id" type="text" attr="attrValue"/></div>'
    };
});
```

Question 1: How would I place `attr="attrValue"` specifically on `input` element / mark-up?

Suppose I want to write:

```
<my-directive ... readonly></my-directive>
```

Question 2: How can I pass `readonly` property to the `input` element in the template?

```
app.directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        template:
            '<div><label>Label: </label><input id="my-id" type="text" readonly/></div>'
    };
});
```

Comment: This is actually not so simple to solve. I had a similar use case of creating a `<label>` ed input and ended up doing quite a `compile` function for it. Any way, the solution for me was to create a directive that wraps the `<input/>` element I wanted to modify like `<labeled-input><input ... /></labeled-input>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `template` property of directive configuration can be a function that receives element and attributes as arguments and returns the template ([see documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile)). You can then use these data when constructing the template:

```
.directive('...', function () {
    return {
        template: function (tElement, tAttrs) {
            return '... <input ...' + (tAttrs.readonly ? ' readonly' : '') + '> ...';
        },
        // ...
    };
});
```